# Using 50% height to viewport if target element is deeply nested

Tags: html, css, height

I'm not entirely sure about the following issue:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="group">
      <a>
        <div class="col-lg-3 full-h"></div>
      </a>
      <a>
        <div class="col-lg-3 full-h"></div>
      </a>
      <a>
        <div class="col-lg-3 full-h"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

.full-h { 
  height: 50%; 
}
```

do I need to set the height of `container, row and group` to `height: 100%` as well to make `full-h` apply properly? If I don't set it, it does not work.

Comment: I'm afraid so, that is how percentage height works, also if any of the parent is not set to 100% then it all breaks (apart of any viewport units).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to set height to 100% to all parent elements of your target.

Another way of doing this is to set the height of the target element to 50vh, which means 50% of the viewport height. In this case, you don't have to rely on the height of the parent elements.

```
.full-h { 
  height: 50vh; 
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fd6n8p7p/1/